# Rspec: Check if array includes object which includes property

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, rspec

I have a json array full of objects.

```
my_array = [{id => 6, name => "bob"}, 
           {id => 5, name => "jim"}, 
           {id => 2, name => "steve"}]
```

I need to see if the array holds an object which contains an attribute "id" that is set to 5. The "name" attribute is unknown.

How do I do this in rspec?

I know if I had the name attribute I know I could just do:

```
my_array.should include({:id => 5, :name => "jim"})
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
expect(myArray.find { |item| item[:id] == 5 }).to_not be_nil
```

or with the legacy should syntax

```
myArray.find { |item| item[:id] == 5 }.should_not be_nil
```

Please note that `myArray` is not following Ruby conventions. Variables use underscore

```
my_array
```

not camelcase

```
myArray
```

Comment: Bonus points for teaching proper Ruby naming conventions. Bravo!

Comment: For anyone who is looking for a solution with RSpec 3 at their disposal. Check out RSpecs new composable matchers.

Comment: I recommend checking out the next solution, I think it's a bit more elegant/readable: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54238804/1128742

Answer (score 32):

It is also possible using the having_attributes alias:

```
expect(my_array).to include( an_object_having_attributes(id: 5) )
```

or, as in my own use case, matching the whole array:

```
expect(my_array).to contain_exactly(
  an_object_having_attributes(id: 5),
  an_object_having_attributes(id: 6),
  an_object_having_attributes(id: 2)
)
```

Comment: A similar solution for an array of hashes (what I was looking for when I found this post):
`expect(my_array).to include(a_hash_including(id: 5))`

Comment: Notice `having_attributes` and `have_attributes` are matcher aliases for `an_object_having_attributes`, so you can use the one you think fits better.

Answer (score 6):

You can unfold an array and to check matching of two arrays like here:

```
expect(my_array).to include(*compare_array)
```

It'll unfold and match each value of array.

It's equivalent to this:

```
expected([1, 3, 7]).to include(1,3,7)
```

Source: [Relish documentation](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/2-0/docs/matchers/include-matcher#array-usage)

Answer (score 3):

This would only be worth it if you were doing many of these, but you could define a [custom matcher](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-0/docs/built-in-matchers/include-matcher#fuzzy-usage-with-matchers):

```
RSpec::Matchers.define :object_with_id do |expected|
  match do |actual|
    actual[:id] == expected
  end
  description do
    "an object with id '#{expected}'"
  end
end

# ...

myArray.should include(object_with_id 5)
```

Answer (score 2):

Put this `any` matcher into `spec/support/matchers.rb` and require it in your `spec_helper.rb`

```
RSpec::Matchers.define :any do |matcher|
  match do |actual|
    actual.any? do |item|
      matcher.matches?(item)
    end
  end
end
```

Then you can use it in examples like this:

```
expect(my_array).to any(include(id: 5))
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use the RSpec 3's composable `include` matcher like so:

```
expect(my_array).to include(include(id: 5))
```

This would have the benefit of a more verbose output via RSpec in case of failure.

```
it 'expects to have element with id 3' do
  my_array = [
    { id: 6, name: "bob" },
    { id: 5, name: "jim" },
    { id: 2, name: "steve" }
  ]
  expect(my_array).to include(include(id: 3))
end
```

This would generate following failure message:

```
Failures:

  1) Test expects to have element with id
     Failure/Error: expect(my_array).to include(include(id: 3))

       expected [{:id => 6, :name => "bob"}, {:id => 5, :name => "jim"}, {:id => 2, :name => "steve"}] to include (include {:id => 3})
       Diff:
       @@ -1,2 +1,2 @@
       -[(include {:id => 3})]
       +[{:id=>6, :name=>"bob"}, {:id=>5, :name=>"jim"}, {:id=>2, :name=>"steve"}]
```

Further reading:

https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/composing-matchers

Answer (score 1):

I see there are many responses, but here is an implementation that was helpful for me on a case which you need to check for multiple key-value pairs on each array object, instead of single attribute checking

**Usage**

```rb
expect(array).to include(have_attributes_with_values({ id: 5, name: 'Jim' }))
```

**Matcher implementation**

```rb
RSpec::Matchers.define :have_attributes_with_values do |expected|
  match do |actual|
    expected.each do |key, value|
      return false unless actual[key] == value
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a customer matcher "include_object" (probably a better name should be used since it just checks if the id's are present)

used as follows

```
obj = {id:1}
objs = [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}]
expect(objs).to include_object obj
```

Matcher can handle Object, Hashs (symbols or string)
It also prints just the id's in the array on exception for easier viewing

```
RSpec::Matchers.define :include_object do |expected|
  ids = []
  match do |actual|
    ids = actual.collect { |item| item['id'] || item[:id] || item.id }

    ids.find { |id| id.to_s == expected.id.to_s }
  end

  failure_message_for_should_not do |actual|
    "expected that array with object id's #{ids} would contain the object with id '#{expected.id}'"
  end

  failure_message_for_should_not do |actual|
    "expected that array with object id's #{ids} would not contain the object with id '#{expected.id}'"
  end
end
```